# How to Log spanId in Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: node.js, gcloud, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to log traceId and spanId in log so that I can correlate trace and log in stackdriver.

I am creating a json logs as follows:
{
  'logging.googleapis.com/trace': traceId,
  'spanId': spanId,
  'message': 'Some message',
}

Now traceid is getting pushed properly in EntryLog but spanId is getting pushed inside jsonPayload.

Answer (score 1):

It is advised that you set the LogEntry span_id with the key “logging.googleapis.com/span_id” [Here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/viewing-trace-spans-and-request-logs-in-multi-project-deployments), because it seems you setting for only trace that is the reason you only able to push TraceID inside jsonPayload. 
Here is a [table](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields) on Special fields in structured payloads.